# Fancybox 2 is not working in Chrome and IE though firefox and Safari are fine

Tags: jquery, fancybox

If you look at this page https://www.social-cat.com/rwewho/index.php You can click on the people or cities and fancybox opens up with an iframe. This works perfect in Firefox and Safari.

Though IE only shows a warning that it doesn't show the unsecure elements (sorry i don't know what it says in english exactly) (and if you click on a picture it only loads the page and no fancybox)  if i click "allow" it works fine.

In chrome it just loads the page out of the iframe without opening fancybox.

Can anyone help me figure out what i could do? I thought it might be an SSL issue but my hoster says everything is alright with this. So maybe something in the code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsecure resource could be the jQuery lib from Google. Try calling it via https.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy! Yes that worked. Thank you very much!

Did you have any ssl problems with the https://www.social-cat.com page itself to load? Because on another new computer i always get an ssl error there in firefox. (sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Comment: https://www.social-cat.com/ leads to a plesk default page, but on the link you posted before are no issues regarding the certificate visible for me.

Comment: Yes it should lead there. It's not a website. So it seems working alright now the app. Though i really have no idea why i get this ssl warning on one computer. Might test it with others.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```